# How can I turn off Lightroom's backup notice?

Tags: lightroom, software

I only use Lightroom for photo manipulation — I don't want or need the catalog feature. Nonetheless, Lightroom repeatedly pesters me with messages asking me to back the catalog up.

How do I disable these messages?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Lightroom always uses a catalog to store your edits, however you can disable the backup notifications.

Go to: Edit->Catalog Settings (PC) OR Lightroom->Catalog Settings (Mac)

[image: Lightroom Edit Menu]

Set: "Back up catalog" to "Never"

[image: Lightroom Catalog Settings]

Comment: Perfect. Note that on a Mac, it's in Lightroom > Catalog Settings...

Answer (score 2):

Edit->Preferences->General->Go to catalog settings->General->Backup->Never

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are correct, but I'm not sure why one would want to disable this function. All the develop adjustments are stored in the catalog, so if the catalog file crashes you'd lose all your adjustments (other than any exported files you'd made, of course - but these wouldn't tell you what specific adjustments you'd done, they'd only give you a jpg or tif output from those adjustments). Having a regular (even if only monthly or so) backup of the catalog seems very useful to me, even if you never use the Library function.

Comment: A good point. Note also that you *can* have your changes written to sidecar XMP files, so the catalog isn't responsible for holding changes.

Comment: @DanWolfgang Sure, but information stored in the sidecar XMP files are not equivalent to the catalog. They only store a small part of the information in the catalog and some features such as virtual copies are lost.

Comment: Also a good point, @Hugo! Really, people who believe that the catalog is evil just need to get over themselves and use it.