# How can I make Lightroom always backup on exit without the dialog asking everytime?

Tags: lightroom, software, backup, lightroom-catalog

I've found many answers for how to disable the backup dialog, but they all involve turning off backups (like [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/63572/how-can-i-turn-off-lightrooms-backup-notice?newreg=1767aca385c048c9b22cd3fcbd21ae9e)). I want Lightroom to **always backup** the catalog upon exiting, but I want to set the backup settings once and then **never see the dialog again**.

The main reason for this is to allow my mac to apply automatic system upgrades, which involves restarting, but Lightroom blocks that because of the backup dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Setting an option like this is also not a very good idea for the following reason: Catalog Backup in Lightroom also means "Optimizing" the catalog for faster access on future usage. This is an operation that **can take a long time**. Almost certainly, if you want to reboot your macOS, it will ask to force-quit Lightroom, because it needs too much time to shutdown. If you do that, you risk a broken catalog.

IMHO your best option is to disable the automatic backup and do it manually from time to time.

Comment: "If you want to reboot your macOS, it will ask to force-quit Lightroom" - The optimisations don't take long on this mac (5-7 seconds max), so I assume it would wait for the program to quit. Do you know any info how long OSX will wait for quitting programs?

I disagree with disabling auto backup as my best option: it's best to leave it as is (always backing up) and get used to the dialog always appearing. Better safe than sorry!

It's a shame I can't hide the dialog. Thanks for answering though: accepted!

Comment: I can't give you exact numbers, but I would guess something around 15-30 seconds max. I would also not bet on the optimisation to always be faster than that - if you have a big catalog it can take *a lot* longer. Third, I agree with you to be better safe than sorry, I meant that disabling the backup is pretty much your only option if you want to get rid of that dialog...